# How to use dotenv on gitlab CI?

Tags: node.js, gitlab-ci, gatsby

I'm struggling with gatsby build on gitlab CI. I'm using .env file to provide variable with SITE_URL.

From my gatsby config

```
import type { GatsbyConfig } from "gatsby";

const result = require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
});

if (result.error) {
  console.error(result.error);
}

const config: GatsbyConfig = {
  siteMetadata: {
    siteUrl: process.env.SITE_URL,
....
```

And this is how I configure pages job in pipeline editor

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  needs: 
    - yarn:install
    - test:gatsby
  script:
    - echo SITE_URL=$SITE_URL >> .env.production
    - echo $SITE_URL
    - cat .env.production
    - ./node_modules/.bin/gatsby build --prefix-paths
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

From logs it seems that .env.production is correct

```
$ echo SITE_URL=$SITE_URL >> .env.production
$ echo $SITE_URL
https://my_www.gitlab.io/my_www-3.0/
$ cat .env.production
SITE_URL=https://my_www.gitlab.io/my_www-3.0/
```

But it does not work at gatsby's side:

```
error The site's gatsby-config failed validation:
"siteMetadata.siteUrl" must be a valid uri
```

As apparently, the process.env does not contain SITE_URL

How can I debug the root cause of that?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in configuration of Gitlab pages. It is necessary to select:

**Use unique domain**

And use the generated url as SITE_URL, instead of subdomain.